# Select rows only if they match a specific string

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a dataset with 5 numerical columns, say {A,B,C,D,E}, 
in which the value of any column can vary from 1 to 100. i.e,

1 <= all values in A/B/C/D/E <= 100

and our dataset looks like this :

```
A  B  C  D  E  
1  5  7  19 2    
90 12 8  45 30  
30 10 20 50 40 #need this row  
33 11 22 55 44  
50 40 10 20 30 #and this row  
40 40 10 20 30 #not this one
```

and I want to filter only those rows which contain each one of the following 5 values, e.g.: {10,20,30,40,50}. the order doesn't matter but the 5 columns should contain all the 5 values.

So the output should be like this :

```
A  B  C  D  E    
30 10 20 50 40  
50 40 10 20 30
```

I tried using a lot of `ifelse` to filter for all the 5 column conditions but the thing is that I need to apply this concept to a more complex problem where they may not be a defined no. of columns or even a defined 'lookup' dataset. so any solution using dplyr, data.table, tidyverse is much appreciated, but any other creative one anyone can come up with please do share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tb <- data.frame(A = c(1, 90, 30 ,33,50,40),
                 B = c(5,12,10,11,40,40),
                 C = c(7,8,20,22,10,10),
                 D = c(19,45,50,55,20,20),
                 E = c(2,30,40,44,30,30))

cols <- paste0(c(10,20,30,40,50), collapse = "_")

index <- apply(tb, 1, function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = "_") == cols)

tb[index,]
```

Comment: thanks! changing rows to strings and then comparing them, that actually helps me more.

Answer (score 2):

Using `apply`, `sum`, and `%in%` from base `R`

```
my_vals = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
df[apply(df, 1, function(row) all(my_vals %in% row)), ]

   A  B  C  D  E
3 30 10 20 50 40
5 50 40 10 20 30
```

This can be extended to any number of columns, and all you have to do is update `my_vals`.

#### Edit

Based on OP's comment regarding a situation to get correct rows picked when `my_vals` might have duplicated elements, the above code can be modified a bit like this

```
my_vals = sort(c(10, 20, 30, 40, 40))
df[apply(df, 1, function(row) all(my_vals == sort(row))), ]

   A  B  C  D  E
6 40 40 10 20 30
```

Comment: fyi, when `my_vals = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 40)`, this solution will also pick up `c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)`

Comment: Ah, yes, because that was not the listed use case. So in that case, you do not want the row with 50 in it?  Because given your condition in the question, if a row has 10,20,30,40,50 in it, it still has all the elements given in `my_vals = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 40)` plus an additional 50.

Comment: you're right. with my_vals = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 40), it will pick up the 5th row in my dataset too. and I dont want it, since its important that only rows get picked up which also have as many instances of all the values in my_vals. I mean that if my_vals = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 40) then only the row with two 40s in it, one 30, one 20 and one 10 in it will get picked up... hope thats clear enough.

Comment: I have updated the answer to accommodate your new condition

Comment: @nsinghs Thanks for the edit. This works better for me now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(paste(sort(c(A, B, C, D, E)), collapse = ".") == "10.20.30.40.50") %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 2 x 5
      A     B     C     D     E
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    30    10    20    50    40
2    50    40    10    20    30
```

Data:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "A  B  C  D  E  
1  5  7  19 2    
90 12 8  45 30  
30 10 20 50 40
33 11 22 55 44  
50 40 10 20 30
40 40 10 20 30", header = TRUE)
```

Note: I'm not sure if this will be a good approach to expand to your *"more complex problem where they may not be a defined no. of columns or even a defined 'lookup' dataset"*, as that's somewhat vaguely defined. If you have a more complex problem, I strongly suggest that you frame your question to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method reshaping to a long format, filtering, and the reshaping back to wide:

```
my_vals = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  gather("col", "val", -id) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(all(my_vals %in% val)) %>%
  spread(col, val)

# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Groups:   id [2]
     id     A     B     C     D     E
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     3    30    10    20    50    40
2     5    50    40    10    20    30
```

(You can, of course, drop the `id` column if you don't want it.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- setDT(read.table(text = "A  B  C  D  E  
  1  5  7  19 2    
  90 12 8  45 30  
  30 10 20 50 40
  33 11 22 55 44  
  50 40 10 20 30
  40 40 10 20 30", header = TRUE))

dt = dt[, .SD[all(seq(10, 50, 10) %in% .SD)], by = 1:nrow(dt)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option without sorting each row.

The idea is to join each column of the dataset with lookup values, column by column. For e.g. for column A, use all 5 values to filter the original dataset.

Then, for column B, join using whatever was not used in column A for each subset of dataset from the previous step.

Then, for column C, join using whatever was not used in column A and B for each subset of dataset from the previous step.

Then, for column D, join using whatever was not used in column A, B and C for each subset of dataset from the previous step.

So on and so forth.

Here is an implementation of the above idea in `data.table`:

```
v <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 40)
nm <- names(dat)

dat <- dat[.(A=unique(v)), on=.(A), nomatch=0L]

for (k in seq_along(nm)[-1L]) {
    dat <- dat[, .SD[.(unique(v[-match(.BY, v)])), 
                     on=eval(nm[k]), 
                     nomatch=0L], 
        by=eval(nm[seq_len(k)[-k]])]
}
dat
```

output for `v <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 40)`:

```
    A  B  C  D  E
1: 10 40 40 20 30
2: 40 40 10 20 30
3: 40 40 10 20 30
```

output for `v <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)`:

```
    A  B  C  D  E
1: 30 10 20 50 40
2: 50 40 10 20 30
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("A  B  C  D  E  
1  5  7  19 2    
90 12 8  45 30
30 10 20 50 40
33 11 22 55 44
50 40 10 20 30
40 40 10 20 30  
40 40 10 20 30    
10 40 40 20 30")     #2 dupe rows to demonstrate edge case
```